# Vba - Resize chart to fit number of value

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm working with chart in Excel/Vba and I've got this chart causing troubles :
[image]

I want the X value (B/C/D/E/F) to fit all the graph width. Does anyone has a macro for that ?

Comment: What is the sourcedata set as? Are you referencing blank cells as well?

Comment: I might be referencing blanks spaces but the chart can have maximum 15 letters in X axis. It's random and I want to delete the empty value with a macro.

Comment: So find the actual range and set the sourcedata via code :)

Comment: have you tried creating a dynamic named range?

Answer (score 1):

Turn your source data into an Excel Table object with Ctrl-T or Insert > Table. Then create the chart based on the table.

[image]

When you add more data to the table, the chart will refresh. The X axis of the chart will only show data that exists in the table.

The crucial bit here is to NOT pre-populate the table with rows that don't yet have values for the chart. so don't put in empty rows where you only have a label in column A, but no values for the series.

If your data table has empty rows, you can filter the table to show only rows with data, and the chart will ignore the rows that are filtered out. See how rows 7 and 8 are not showing in the filtered table and the chart shows the x values f and i without any gap in the charting lines.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`SetSourceData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841196.aspx) function to update the range of the chart.

Example data set with 'unwanted' items:
[image]

VBA to update the source data:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim chto As ChartObject
    Dim cht As Chart

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- update to your sheet
    Set chto = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1") '<-- update to your chart
    Set cht = chto.Chart
    cht.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("A1:F2") '<-- update to your range

End Sub
```

Updated example:
[image]

Other relevant questions:

- [VBA Chart setsourcedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375833/vba-chart-setsourcedata)
- [Setting a chart source data based on a variable cell range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388270/setting-a-chart-source-data-based-on-a-variable-cell-range-in-vba)